# Infinity is equal to Infinity in Java

Tags: java

I wanted to test if infinity is equal to infinity in Java:

```
Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY
```

I was surprised by the result when it turned out to be true. My question is how can two infinite values be equal?

Comment: Because they represent the same number...?

Comment: An unquantifiable amount can be equal to itself as also an unquantifiable amount.

Comment: Infinity behaves as a regular number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Large_countable_ordinals As opposed to `NaN`, which by definiiton is _not_ a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` represents a specific number, so comparing it to itself using `==` should return true.

This behaviour is specified explicitly in [JLS Sec 15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> Floating-point equality testing is performed in accordance with the rules of the IEEE 754 standard:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, two distinct floating-point values are considered unequal by the equality operators.
>
>   In particular, there is one value representing positive infinity and one value representing negative infinity; each compares equal only to itself, and each compares unequal to all other values.